# Call terminal and run command through Java App

Tags: java, linux, shell, process, terminal

I'm using the followig code to run a command from my Java App:

```
String cmd[] = {"sh","-c", "sudo chmod 777 -R " + path};
Terminal.runCommand(cmd);
```

I'd like to execute the .jar just by click in it and choose "Open with.." -> "Java";

The problem is that the app keep wating for a password because of the "sudo" command, but no terminal is called, the user can't give the password..

So, how could I call the coomand above AND a terminal to give the user a chance to insert the password and the application finally keep going?

Thank very much!

Comment: Are you expecting `ls_exec` to be run with sudo as well? With Process/ProcessBuilder you can read the output and write to the input of a program. What can you do with `Terminal`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I did not expect, in fact I think "le_exec" is not necessary, isn't? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen it before, but it will keep a window open (assuming there is a window) until the user hits enter. I suspect it's not useful here.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Okay, thanks. So, it's not necessary, until we get a window, and I'm looking for to get that window.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sudo question, not a Java one; sudo does things as root.  Your process doesn't have root priviledges, so sudo needs to authenticate the human being.  That's a feature, not a bug.  The system is not supposed to allow you to run root commands.

One option might be to use `gksu` instead, which is shipped by default on some distributions.  It works similarly, but will pop up the password dialog in the GUI instead of on the (in this case non-existent) terminal.

Another might be to simply run your Java process as root, with all the security implications that might have.  In some situations that can be a valid choice, but be careful.

Or you can check the man page for sudo and sudoers -- it's possible to configure accounts not to require a password, and to limit them to particular commands when they do.

Comment: I think it's both, because I'm using sudo from a Java app. I know it's a feature and I'm not saying it's a bug. I'll try to use gksu as you said, I'll let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: You would have exactly the same problem calling it from a C, Python, Ruby, Mono or Perl app.  It's not a Java problem.

Comment: it didn't work for me. I think I've found a way to do that, I'll try to use "echo password | sudo -S chmod 777 -R path". I'll prompt a field using Java(rsrs) for the user input the password and then pass in the place of "password" in the command above. I'm going home now, tomorrow I'll post the result. Thank you.